# Programming Computer Vision With Python Chapter 7

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am following the book written by Jan Erik Solem.

I am a little confused with Chapter 7, the bit about adding images into SQLite dataset.

In the method "add_to_index",

imwords is a list of histogram,

```
imwords = self.voc.project(descr)
```

The code following is confusing me:

```
word = imwords[i]
#wordid is the word number itself
self.con.execute("insert into imwords(imid,wordid,vocname) values (?,?,?)", (imid,word,self.voc.name)
```

It is confusing me because imwords[i] would only give the frequency of the word in the vocabulary, and it wouldn't indication which word is that.

Hence I am thinking, if we want to add words that an image has, should it be like it instead:

```
word = imwords[i]
if word > 0:
    self.con.execute("insert into imwords(imid,wordid,vocname) values (?,?,?)", (imid,i,self.voc.name))
```

Note, i have replaced *word* with *i* in the sql statement.

Comment: just contact the author and ask him. it's his book so he should know best. ;)

Comment: Just took a quick glance at the online draft version of your book. It seems strange indeed. Plus, wouldn't a signature for an image be more meaningful if it where composed of these word frequencies instead of their Ids? I just think that the comment is false but the code is fine.